# mysql_query() error (Invalid Query) in a searcher php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

this is a searcher program php with MySqL this give me a error, and i need a bit help on this...

This is the php Code:

```
<?php 
if ($_POST['buscar'])
{
// Tomamos el valor ingresado
$buscar = $_POST['palabra'];
// Si está vacío, lo informamos, sino realizamos la búsqueda
if(empty($buscar))
{
echo "No se ha ingresado una cadena a buscar";
}else{
//Conexión a la base de datos
$servidor = "localhost"; //Nombre del servidor
$usuario = "root"; //Nombre de usuario en tu servidor
$password = "1234"; //Contraseña del usuario
$base = "db_maquinas"; //Nombre de la BD
$con = mysql_connect($servidor, $usuario, $password) or die("Error al conectarse al servidor");
mysql_select_db($base, $con) or die("Error al conectarse a la base de datos");
$sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM repuestos WHERE id LIKE '%$buscar%' AND descripcion LIKE '%$buscar%' ORDER BY id", $con) or die(mysql_error($con)); 
$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);  //<----LINE 32!!!
// Tomamos el total de los resultados
if($result) { $total = mysql_num_rows($result); } else { die('Invalid query' . mysql_error($con)); }
  echo "<table border = '1'> \n"; 
//Mostramos los nombres de las tablas 
echo "<tr> \n"; 
while ($field = mysql_fetch_field($result)){ 
        echo "<td>$field->name</td> \n"; 
} 
  echo "</tr> \n"; 
  do { 
        echo "<tr> \n"; 

        echo "<td>".$row["id"]."</td> \n"; 

        echo "<td>".$row["descripcion"]."</td> \n"; 

        echo "<td>".$row["cantidad"]."</td> \n"; 

        echo "</tr> \n"; 

  } while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));

        echo "</table> \n"; 
echo "¡ No se ha encontrado ningún registro !"; 
} 
}
?>
```

The error is --> `Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in C:\xampp\htdocs\maquinas2000\paginas\buscarepuestos.php on line 32
Invalid query  {Line 32 is -> $result = mysql_query($sql, $con); }`

i work with a Localhost xampp ofc, this give me a lot of troubles this code, i need only this and i'll finish 100% the work, so if anyone can give me the answer of this error i'll be very grateful for that, thx!

Comment: You're passing the return value of `mysql_query()` to `mysql_query()` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already executed the query. [mysql_query](http://php.net/mysql_query) return `true` or `false` and you are passing this return value again in `mysql_query` , make changes this :

```
 $sql= "SELECT * FROM repuestos WHERE id LIKE '%$buscar%' AND descripcion LIKE '%$buscar%' ORDER BY id";// remove mysql_query from this line
 $result = mysql_query($sql, $con);
```

**Important :** mysql_ is depricated use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead of that

Comment: Good! now work but not at all... i put my value on the search and that dont give me error.. but does not give me the value what i search... give only a Blank page.. but if i dont put the value it give me the first `echo "No se ha ingresado una cadena a buscar";` that work good in that way, but idk why that give me the blank page when i put the value 
PD: Really sorry for my bad english >.< i'm on process of learn it

Comment: `var_dump` your query and run in to `phpmyadmin`, As this scnerio is different from your above question than in order to get better answers post the another question for this query.